# ARM Assembly. How can I take both char and decimal input in the same line

Tags: assembly, input, char, arm, decimal

I have an output that says "Put in 1, 2, or 3 to continue, or press T to end"
Handling either just char, or just decimal is easy, but I can not figure out how to accept an input that can handle both.

My (poor) attempt so far looks like this.

```
*code to get input here, goes into r1*
cmp r1, #'T'
beq exit
cmp r1, #1
blt tryagain
cmp r3, #3
bgt tryagain


.data
.balign 4
numInput: .asciz "%d"
```

Of course I understand this isn't how you handle this situation, but I have no clue what to do

Comment: Please include your "code to get input" in the question.

Comment: You can't use `%d` to input a `T`. Use `getchar` or a `%c` and check against the ascii code of `'1'` and `'3'`.

Comment: @jester Thank you! That fixed my problem